# SSIS packages deployment

Tags: deployment, ssis-2008

We are running into a deployment nightmare with our current setup :

```
1 - DEV makes changes to SSIS 
2 - All the packages that change have to be uploaded again to MSDB
3 - once the deployment is done we use dtexe /SQL switch
```

What we would like essentially is to remove Step 2 and deply the dtsx as files rather then upload it to MSDB, this way anytime DEV changes that need to go to production are just file pushes.

For that purpose we can use dtexec /F switch

The question I had is, is there a way to still use /SQL switch and have it use File system so that deployments are trasparent or is there some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the following solution:

```
Use dtsx packages as files rather then uploading to MSDB.
Use the /F switch inside /COM (Command file)
```